# Button for overlay menu disappears when menu is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I place my menu button inside my header div and open the menu, the close button disappears. This happens after the overlay on the screen. I have tried to fix this with the z-index but nothing changes. I can only see the open button when the menu is closed inside the header. The close menu button shows when the button is not placed inside a header div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button a").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
       $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
    $(".button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    open = false;
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration:none;
 list-style:none;
}
li {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

/*styling open close button*/
.button {
 padding:10px;
 display:inline;
 position:fixed;
 right:50px;
 top:6px;
 z-index:999;
 font-size:30px;
}
.button a {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.btn-open:after {
 color:#071914;
 content:"\f0c9";
 font-family:"FontAwesome";
 transition-property:all .2s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -o-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-open:hover:after {
 color:#fafd23;
}
.btn-close:after {
 color:#071914;
 content:"\f00d";
 font-family:"FontAwesome";
 z-index:100;
 transition-property:all .2s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -o-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
}

.btn-close:hover:after {
 color: #fafd23;
}
/*overlay*/
.overlay {
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background:#FFF;
 overflow:auto;
 z-index:99;
}

/** SOCIAL ICON **/
.wrap {
 color:#f2f2f2;
 text-align:center;
 max-width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.wrap ul.wrap-nav {
 border-bottom:1px solid #071914;
 text-transform:capitalize;
 padding:100px 0px 50px;
}
.wrap ul.wrap-nav li {
 font-size:1.7em;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 width:24%;
 position:relative;
}
.wrap ul.wrap-nav li a {
 color:#071914;
 display:block;
 padding:8px 0;
 text-decoration:none;
 transition-property:all .2s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -o-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
}

.wrap-nav h1{
 color:#071914;
 font-family:'spinweradbold';
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:1px;
}

.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul {
 padding:20px 0;
}
.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li {
 display:block;
 font-size:.7em;
 width:100%;
 color:#e9e9e9;
}
.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li a {
 color:#071914;
}
.wrap ul.wrap-nav ul li a:hover {
 color:#6dd7d7;
}

.social {
 font-size:25px;
 padding:20px;
}
.social p {
 margin:0;
 padding:20px 0 5px 0;
 line-height:30px;
 font-size:13px;
}

.social-icon {
 width:80px;
 height:50px;
 background:#071914;
 color:#fff;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0 20px;
 transition-property:all .2s linear 0s;
 -moz-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -webkit-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
 -o-transition:all .2s linear 0s;
}
.social-icon:hover {
 background:#6dd7d7;
 color:#FFF;
}
.social-icon i {
 margin-top:12px;
}

.content {
 width:100%;
 margin-top:200px;
 font-size:20px;
 color#333;
 text-align: center;
}


@media screen and (max-width:48em) {
 .button{
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-right:-30px; 
 }
 
 .wrap ul.wrap-nav>li {
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #6dd7d7;
 }
 .wrap ul.wrap-nav {
  padding:30px 0px 0px;
 }
 nav ul {
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
 }
 .social {
  color:#c1c1c1;
  font-size:25px;
  padding:15px 0;
 }
 .social-icon {
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:#fff;
  color:#333;
  display:block;
  margin:5px 0;
 }
 
 .social p {
 margin:0;
 padding:20px 0 5px 0;
 line-height:30px;
 font-size:5px;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="header-section">
    <div class="logo">
        <a class="logo-img" href="#home"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="button">
        <a class="btn-open" href="#current"></a>
    </div>
</div><!--end of header-->

    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="wrap">
            <ul class="wrap-nav">
                <li><h1>main</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bio">Biography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="resume/n-co-resume-web.pdf" target="_blank">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><h1>web</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#dig">Ad Designs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#web">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#mockups">Mockups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#wire">Wireframes</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><h1>graphic</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#logo">Logo Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#typography">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#color">Color Theory</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><h1>illustration</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#ifa">Illustrations</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="http://linkedin.com/in/natishacorona" target="_blank">
                <div class="social-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                </div>
                </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/GAN_N" target="_blank">
                <div class="social-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                </div>
                </a>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div><!--header-main-->
```

Comment: where is the overlay div placed? your code is missing.

Comment: the code snippet is broken.

Comment: something is broken in your snippet...